# SELinux is blocking connections from Amavis back into itself: no way in/out?

Tags: postfix, selinux, amavis

Running a fresh CentOS8 install here, MTA is Postfix with Amavis hooked in. I want to have Amavis inject messages from ORIGINATING (incoming submissions from port 587/Postfix through 10026/Amavis) back into Amavis (port 10024) after (internal) DKIM signing. But port 10024 has already been assigned for listening for incoming smtp connections from 25/Postfix, so I cannot add it as a sending-to port in the SELinux configuration.

The messages flow:

- 25/smtp -> Postfix -> smtp-amavis/10024
- 10024 -> Amavis: scan -> 10025
- 10025 -> Postfix -> delivery
- 587/submission -> Postfix -> smtp-amavis/10026
- 10026 -> Amavis ORIGINATING: scan & DKIM sign -> smtp-amavis/10024

The problem I run into is that SELinux does not allow me to feed messages from the last flow back into smtp-amavis at port 10024 (Amavis to Amavis) because this port has already been assigned for receiving:

```
[root@services amavisd]# semanage port -l | grep 1002
amavisd_recv_port_t            tcp      10026, 10024
amavisd_send_port_t            tcp      10027, 10025
spamd_port_t                   tcp      783, 10026, 10027
```

Interestingly, SELinux did not complain about ports 10026, 10027 already being assigned to spamd when I added then to amavisd_recv_port_t and amavisd_send_port_t respectively:

```
[root@services amavisd]# semanage port -lC
SELinux Port Type              Proto    Port Number
amavisd_recv_port_t            tcp      10026
amavisd_send_port_t            tcp      10027
```

How can I fix this? as SELinux does not allow me to add 10024 as a sending port too:

```
[root@services amavisd]# semanage port -a -t amavisd_send_port_t -p tcp 10024
ValueError: Port tcp/10024 already defined
```

**Or am I going completely the wrong way with this**, and should submitted messages not be fed back into Amavis through port 10024 at all (which makes this an Amavis rather than an SELinux question)? For originally the Amavis configuration forwarded submitted messages to port 10027 for (external) DKIM signing by OpenDKIM, as you can see here:

```
# forward to a smtpd service providing DKIM signing service
#forward_method => 'smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10027',
forward_method => 'smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10024',
```

So the last flow originally was:

- 10026 -> Amavis ORIGINATING: scan -> OpenDKIM@10027: sign -> delivery

But OpenDKIM is not (yet) available for CentOS8 (used to be via the EPEL repo), and Amavis now supports an internal DKIM signing service that I'm trying to use.

So there are two ways out I see:

- configure SELinux so that it can feed DKIM-signed messages from the submission flow back into the basic smtp flow
  (assuming that this somewhat loopy set-up works)
- keep the original Amavis configuration, which means that there will have to be a service behind port 10027 that delivers outgoing (i.e. submitted) messages

Which way to go, and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I oversaw the most obvious solution (following an incorrect online recipe): feed the Amavis ORIGINATING flow back into port 10025 for delivery by Postfix (thereby funnelling the 25/smtp and 587/submission flows after separate handling by Amavis). This also circumvents the SELinux issue, as there is no longer the need to feed messages from Amavis back into itself.

So the whole scheme now looks like this:

- 25/smtp -> Postfix -> smtp-amavis/10024
- 10024 -> Amavis: scan -> 10025
- 10025 -> Postfix -> delivery
- 587/submission -> Postfix -> smtp-amavis/10026
- 10026 -> Amavis ORIGINATING: scan & DKIM sign -> 10025